# I am trying to implement react component tabs with native base but it is not showing properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tabs, native-base

Hello I am trying to implement rc-tabs in a reactjs project using native base.
but this does not work, the tabs are being showed as text components and the documentation does not help with this case.

this is a web project with native base v3, typescript and react 17.

code:

```js
<Center>

   
    <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={callback} style={{
      padding: 2,
      marginRight: 5
    }} >
    <TabPane tab="tab 1" key="1">
      <Popeyes />
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="tab 2" key="2">
      <Reports />
    </TabPane>
  
  </Tabs>
  </Center>
```

result
[image]

I hope someone can help me with this.